# Unknown Installation Error in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

My console is giving the following error when trying to run an Android Project in Eclipse.

> WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement! Device
>   API version is 15 (Android 4.0.4) Installation error: Unknown failure
>   Please check logcat output for more details. Launch canceled!

I checked the logcat as suggested and there doesn't really seem to be that information in there. All it says is:

> D/AndroidRuntime( 5039): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<< D/AndroidRuntime( 5039):
>   CheckJNI is OFF I/ethernet( 5039): Loading ethernet jni class
>   D/AndroidRuntime( 5039): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
>   D/AndroidRuntime( 5039): Shutting down VM D/dalvikvm( 5039):
>   GC_CONCURRENT freed 97K, 83% free 444K/2560K, paused 0ms+0ms
>   D/dalvikvm( 5039): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1
>   entries I/AndroidRuntime( 5039): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread
>    #1' failed

Would you guys have any suggestions on what I could do to get this sorted out? I'm really new to Java/Android development but trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, u need to download the files first when you open the SDK console for various platforms..v4.0.4 in your case.
Once you download the required APIs etc, you will be able to run it i guess.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm a bit new, so I'm having a hard time understanding your response. But which files should I be downloading? I'm currently in Eclipse trying to run the project, which from what I understand will try to open the SDK emulator that's using 4.0.4. Is that correct so far?

Answer (score 0):

open the sdk manager and install/reinstall the android 4 sdk, restart eclipse and try again

Comment: Thanks for the response! I don't think re-installing is a concern because I only just installed SDK/Eclipse today. However, when I logged into the SDK manager, I noticed only API 19 was installed. So I went and installed 15(4.0.3) and 16(4.1.2) but am still getting the same error :( Any other suggestions? I wonder if the console message even have anything to do with this, since the console only gives a warning that I never specified an API requirement. Any other suggestions on what I could do to get this sorted out?